# How to make Weld lookup class on generated-sources

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, mapstruct

I have a maven project which i'm using MapStruct to generate mappers to help in the job of translating entities into DTOs and vice-versa.
This mappers are generated during the generate-sources phase of maven, and stored into target/generated-sources and target/AppName/WEB-INF/classes folders.

For example, I have this Mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface RuleMapper {

    RuleDto ruletoDto(Rule rule);

    //other cool stuf
}
```

I configurated MapStruct to use CDI, so it will generate the following:

```
@Generated(
value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
date = "2016-12-19T23:19:36-0200",
comments = "version: 1.1.0.CR1, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_112"
)
@Singleton
@Named
public class RuleMapperImpl implements RuleMapper {

    @Override
    public RuleDto ruletoDto(Rule rule) {

        ruleDto ruleDto = new ruleDto();

        if ( rule != null ) {
            ruleDto.setIdRule( rule.getIdRule() );
        }

        return ruleDto;
    }
}
```

It works perfectely when running on Wildfly server, the problem is that I'm trying to junit test this class, for this, I implemented a custom runner as shown bellow:

```
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class WeldJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public WeldJUnit4Runner(Class<Object> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
        final Class<?> test = getTestClass().getJavaClass();
        return WeldContext.INSTANCE.getBean(test);
    }

}
```

And:

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;

public class WeldContext {

    public static final WeldContext INSTANCE = new WeldContext();

    private final Weld weld;
    private final WeldContainer container;

    private WeldContext() {
        this.weld = new Weld();
        this.container = weld.initialize();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                weld.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

    public <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
        return container.instance().select(type).get();
    }

}
```

These implementations were taken from [here](http://memorynotfound.com/java-se-unit-testing-cdi-junit-jboss-weld-se/).

Finally, the test:

```
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class RuleMapperTest {

    @Inject
    private RuleMapper ruleMapper;

    @Test
    public void coolTestName() {
        Assert.assertTrue(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

When I try to run, this is the console output:

**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.**

warning about logs, and the following exception:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at br.com.treinoos.common.cdi.WeldJUnit4Runner.createTest(WeldJUnit4Runner.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type RuleMapper with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private br.com.treinoos.model.core.business.treinoos.mappers.RuleMapperTest.ruleMapper
>     at br.com.treinoos.model.core.business.treinoos.mappers.RuleMapperTest.ruleMapper(RuleMapperTest.java:0)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
>       at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Like Weld wasn't abble to lookup the generated class.
The `beans.xml` is already created under `src/test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Can anybody point me a solution to this problem? I've already searched something simillar, but no success.

Comment: Did you also add a `beans.xml` to `src/main/resources/META-INF`?

Comment: Is it the exact same content as you have listed? You mention this one is explicitly `src/test/resources` also please note my path - its not `src/main/webapp`

Comment: @JohnAment I have exactaly this structure: http://imgur.com/dFx6nsn

Comment: Right, as I mentioned try adding to `src/main/resources/META-INF`, and said explicitly not `src/main/webapp` which will only work in a WAR file.  A JUnit test is not in a WAR file.

Comment: It just.... worked. Can't believe it. I thought that for JUnit test it was only necessary the beans.xml to be under src/test/resources.. Well, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full explanation to your problem and why what I wrote fixes it.

In Maven, you have at least 2 classloader.  Your test classpath and your main classpath each have their own classloader.  You can have others depending on your dependency structure.  CDI identifies each classloader as a separate bean archive when running this way.  `src/main/webapp` is explicitly for your WAR file.  The `beans.xml` there does not give you a bean archive.  Adding one to `src/main/resources` does.  This problem is specific to how you're instantiating weld.

There are other projects that do this correctly - [CDI-unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) and [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/weld/), specifically the Weld Embedded container.  If you were to use one of these, this would not be an issue.

Comment: I used CDIUnit, I changed to try and see if the problem was the lib. Anyway, thanks, that helped me.